# How to decrease the width of the tableview cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to decrease the `tableviewcell` width and place imageview on that cell.

And that imageview should contain the ADD Photo text inside it.

Whenever we click on that one then imagepicker is shown and selected picture is place on that cell's imageview.

Please give me any suggestions.

Help me.

Comment: can you PLEASE write in proper english?

Comment: I want to decrease the tableview cell Width.Because i want to place the imageview On that cell .

Comment: have you tried with default imageview provided for cell?

Comment: And show the imageview border as a box before select the image and that contain the "Add Photo" text.

Comment: I placed the default imageview on cell.But before selecting the image imageview is not appeared.So i want to display the imageviewborder also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read the [table view programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451).